# CORS does not allow POST requests

Tags: java, angular, rest, jwt

I am developing a fullstack app and I have encoutnered a problem.

I try to perform POST request from my angular app to spring boot backend app but every time it fails due to CORS. In fact if I change POST to GET request it always succed.

Here is my frontend code:

```
    finalizeRegister(userAccount: UserAccount) {
    return this._httpClient.post(`${Constants.apiRoot}account/finalize`, userAccount);
    }
```

And interceptor:

```
intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
if (req.url.startsWith(Constants.apiRoot)) {
  return from(this._authService.getAccessToken().then(token => {
    const headers = new HttpHeaders().set('Authorization', `Bearer ${token}`);
    const authReq = req.clone({ headers });
    return next.handle(authReq).pipe(tap(_ => { }, error => {
      var respError = error as HttpErrorResponse;
      if (respError && (respError.status === 401 || respError.status === 403)) {
        this._router.navigate(['/unauthorized']);
      }
    })).toPromise();
  }));
}
else {
  return next.handle(req);
}
```

}

Spring boot CORS config:

```
 package pl.daniel.pawlowski.conquerorgame.security;

import com.auth0.spring.security.api.JwtWebSecurityConfigurer;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.http.HttpMethod;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.OAuth2TokenValidator;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.jwt.*;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import java.util.Arrays;

/**
 * Configures our application with Spring Security to restrict access to our API endpoints.
 */
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value( "${auth0.audience}" )
    private String audience;

    @Value("${auth0.issuer}")
    private String issuer;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        JwtWebSecurityConfigurer
                .forRS256(audience, issuer)
                .configure(http)
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/public").permitAll()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/private").authenticated()
                .antMatchers(HttpMethod.GET, "/api/admin/**").hasAuthority("view:admin")
                .anyRequest()
                .authenticated()
                .and()
                .cors();
    }

    @Bean
    JwtDecoder jwtDecoder() {
        /*
        By default, Spring Security does not validate the "aud" claim of the token, to ensure that this token is
        indeed intended for our app. Adding our own validator is easy to do:
        */

        NimbusJwtDecoder jwtDecoder = (NimbusJwtDecoder)
                JwtDecoders.fromOidcIssuerLocation(issuer);

        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> audienceValidator = new AudienceValidator(audience);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withIssuer = JwtValidators.createDefaultWithIssuer(issuer);
        OAuth2TokenValidator<Jwt> withAudience = new DelegatingOAuth2TokenValidator<>(withIssuer, audienceValidator);

        jwtDecoder.setJwtValidator(withAudience);

        return jwtDecoder;
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("http://localhost:4200"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
        return source;
    }


}
```

It seems that there is something wrong in my config because while I try to call any endpoint with POST request, in my browser console I see:

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
> 'http://localhost:8081/api/account/finalize' from origin
> 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request
> header field content-type is not allowed by
> Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: Try using https or set cors on the server side or try adding headers on the client side

Comment: The error seems to indicate that Spring doesn't like the `content-type` header your angular app is sending.  Perhaps there is a way to configure Cors to allow certain (or all) HTTP headers?  Looks like there is: https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/cors/CorsConfiguration.html#setAllowedHeaders-java.util.List-

Comment: thanks @jrahhali, I have set:         configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization","content-type")); and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

You are running on different ports.
Your frontend is being served from `http://localhost:4200` while your backend is running on `http://localhost:8081`.

Since you are running on different ports, the requests are a interpreted as coming from different origins. It doesn't matter that they are on the same machine/hostname, CORS will block it because that is how it's specified.

Either disable CORS or add `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`-header to your HTTP responses.

For more information on the topic, see https://enable-cors.org/